# Is this integer function convex?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n)$ be a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Define the variables $z_i=x_i-\lambda y_i$. For any real number $\lambda$, I define the set $Z^{+}(\lambda)$ of numbers  $$Z^{+}(\lambda) = \{z_i\mid z_i \geq 0\}$$ Thus $Z^{+}$ contains the set of positive numbers among $z_i$ for a given $\lambda$. Now consider the function \begin{align}f(\lambda)=\lvert Z^{+}(\lambda)\rvert\end{align}
where $\lvert . \rvert$ is cardinality of the argument set. Is $f(\lambda)$ concave?

Answer (score 0):

This function is not continuous, and each convex/concave function is continuous, so this function is not convex.